# InitializeComponent() calling another method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, components

When I added the SelectionChanged event and of course the method in the code to handle the event to the following combobox:

```
....

<ComboBox Name="OrderBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="OrderBox_OnSelectionChanged">
       <ComboBoxItem Margin="4,4,4,4" IsSelected="True">Por Nombre (A - Z)</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem Margin="4,4,4,4">Por Nombre (Z - A)</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem Margin="4,4,4,4">Por Apellido (A - Z)</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem Margin="4,4,4,4">Por Apellido (Z - A)</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

....
```

I saw debuging the application after having errors of controls not being initialized that when the application calls **InitializeComponent()** the first thing it does is call my combobox event handler method (**OrderBox_OnSelectionChanged()**). So I can't really use the event of the combobox because every controller is being loaded afterwards.

If I remove the event from the combobox xaml and the eventhandler the error won't happen, even though I have more eventhandlers, is only calling that one for some reason I can't see.

The code is as simple as this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent(); //FROM HERE IT GOES TO OrderBox_OnSelectionChanged()
     Displayer();
}

private void OrderBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}

....
```

Hope you know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: On initialization the comboboxes checkboxes will change from not set to whatever your initial value is. This is because they can´t be *unset*. There´s no way to avoid calling the event-handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `OrderBox.SelectionChanged+=OrderBox_OnSelectionChanged;` in the `MainWindow` constructor and remove the `SelectionChanged` attribute in your xaml.

Comment: Works now, thanks you a lot sir. Though why does the event in the xaml combobox make the constructor load that precise event method before everything else?

Comment: It runs the event, because your xaml code specifies which item is selected on startup, so it changes the SelectedItem and then calls the event. Furthermore you usually don't write "Sir" here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When a form is loaded using the `InitializeComponent();`, the combo boxes on that pages with be set to (usually) their item at the index of -1, unless you explicitly set it otherwise. Either way, the selected item changes to its default when the form is initialized and the `SelectionChanged` event hits. You could work around the event being hit by putting a line of error handling:

```
private void OrderBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (OrderBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested, the call goes into the if condition too, so doesn't work this way..  http://prntscr.com/k3e18o

Comment: @SaFteiNZz my apologies, I didn't see that you had set a selected item in your XAML

Comment: I forgot it myself too, with no selected <ComboBoxItem> and SelectedIndex="-1" as a property of the combobox it works.

Comment: @SaFteiNZz Excellent! If you don't sent the combo box item as Selected, you don't need to expressly state the selected index as -1, though it is always safer to do so.